# Is there a specific name or adjective for an html element that's closed in the opening tag?

Tags: html

For example,

`<p/>` as opposed to

`<p></p>`?

Here I am including some random text, because StackOverflow won't let me post the question otherwise.  It says "it doesn't meet SO's standards.  Maybe it will now with this extra text?

Comment: they are often called "self-closing" tags.

Comment: html element with no content are called empty-element tag

Answer (score 3):

In XML, it is an [empty-element tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags)

In HTML, for that element, it is invalid.

In HTML 4.x and earlier, a tag with no end tag (such as `<br>`) is [empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-element-4).

HTML 5 doesn't appear to give a special name to them, but describes [tag omission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-tag-omission).

Comment: In HTML5 in HTML syntax, `<p/>` is an error, reported by http://validator.nu as “Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.” In XHTML syntax, all XML rules apply, i.e. it is an empty-element tag.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority will call it a "self-closing tag."